# Скрипт создания и очистки старых бекапов

Tags: резервное-копирование, centos, mysql

Всем добрый вечер. Во первых. Когда скрипт бекапит Mysql базу, в каждый файл *.sql самой первой строкой вносит данный код:

```
dd_forum.sql                                                                                        0000644 0000000 0000000 00123227471 12250064572 012122  0                                                                                                    ustar   root                            root                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.71, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

Но тут не видно слов NUL между цифрами, выстроенных вряд, и из-за этого, когда импортируешь sql файл в БД, он ругается на эту строчку. Приходится вручную удалять. Что не есть ГУД.

---

Теперь вопрос №2. В самом низу есть команда удаления файлов, старше 7 дней. Файлы он конечно же удаляет, но папки с датами оставляет. Вопрос. Как удалять папки? Или как эти папки ещё раз в архив загнать?

```
#!/bin/sh#SettingsBACKUP_PATH="/hdd/backup"SITES_DIR="/hdd/site"MCSU_DIR="/hdd/host/mcsu/www"MYSQL_USER="***"MYSQL_PASS="***"MYSQL_HOST="localhost"## MySQL backup # Создание списка БДmysql -h$MYSQL_HOST -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS -e "show databases;" > /tmp/databases.list# Исключаем базы из бекапаEXCLUDES=( 'Database' 'information_schema' 'mysql' )NUM_EXCLUDES=${#EXCLUDES[@]}mkdir $BACKUP_PATH/mysql/`date +%d.%m.%Y`for database in `cat /tmp/databases.list`do  skip=0  let count=0  while [ $count -lt $NUM_EXCLUDES ] ; do    # check if this name in excludes list    if [ "$database" = ${EXCLUDES[$count]} ] ; then      let skip=1    fi    let count=$count+1  done  if [ $skip -eq 0 ] ; then    echo "++ $database"    # now we can backup current database    cd $BACKUP_PATH/mysql/`date +%d.%m.%Y`    backup_name="$database.sql"    backup_tarball_name="$backup_name.gz"    `/usr/bin/mysqldump --lock-tables --add-locks -h"$MYSQL_HOST" --databases "$database" -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASS" > "$backup_name"`    echo "   backup $backup_name"    `/bin/tar -czf "$backup_tarball_name" "$backup_name"`    echo "   compress $backup_tarball_name"    `/bin/rm "$backup_name"`    echo "   cleanup $backup_name"  fidone`/bin/rm /tmp/databases.list`## Files backup#mkdir $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%Y`#mkdir $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%Y`/`date +%d.%m`#cd $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%Y`/`date +%d.%m`mkdir $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%d.%m.%Y`cd $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%d.%m.%Y`for i in `ls $SITES_DIR`; dotar -czf $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%d.%m.%Y`/$i-`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.gz $SITES_DIR/$idone## MCSU backupmkdir $BACKUP_PATH/www/mcsu/`date +%d.%m.%Y`cd $BACKUP_PATH/www/mcsu/`date +%d.%m.%Y`for i in `ls $MCSU_DIR`; dotar -czf $BACKUP_PATH/www/mcsu/`date +%d.%m.%Y`/$i-`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.gz $MCSU_DIR/$idone## MineCraft backupmkdir $BACKUP_PATH/minecraft/first/`date +%d.%m.%Y`cd $BACKUP_PATH/minecraft/first/`date +%d.%m.%Y`tar -czf world-`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.gz /hdd/servers/minecraft/world## Remove old backupsfind $BACKUP_PATH/mysql/ -mtime +7|xargs rm -ffind $BACKUP_PATH/www/ -mtime +7|xargs rm -ffind $BACKUP_PATH/minecraft/first/ -mtime +7|xargs rm -f
```

Comment: Что нужно дописать, что бы архивировалась папка, в которой есть уже архивы бекапов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вопрос непонятен.

> Вопрос. Как удалять папки?

find $BACKUP_PATH/mysql/ -mtime +7|xargs rm -**r**f

Но лучше так не делать, поскольку сам каталог  $BACKUP_PATH/mysql/ может быть -mtime +7.

Поэтому лучше

```
cd $BACKUP_PATH/mysql/find . -mtime +7|xargs rm -rfcd $BACKUP_PATH/www/find . -mtime +7|xargs rm -rf...
```

Вам 2 за невнимательность, две строки с  for , done на конце.

tar -czf $BACKUP_PATH/www/`date +%d.%m.%Y`/$i-`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.gz $SITES_DIR/$i;**done**

tar -czf $BACKUP_PATH/host/`date +%d.%m.%Y`/$i-`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.gz $MCSU_DIR/$i;**done**

Comment: у меня в папке $BACKUP_PATH/www/ создаётся папка с текущей датой, когда был запущен скрипт бекапа. И мне надо подчищать именно ЭТИ старые папки

Comment: ./auto_backup_all.sh: line 83: ошибка синтаксиса: неожиданный конец файла

Comment: Я надеюсь "..." вы не скопировали ? ))) Если нет давайте в студию 83 строку

Comment: cleanup wow_world_new.sqlmkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/hdd/backup/www/05.12.2013»: Файл существует./auto_backup_all.sh: line 81: ошибка синтаксиса: неожиданный конец файлаСкрипт --> http://pastebin.com/hehCduNp

Comment: Добавил в ответ.